# Is it possible to invoke java web service from unix script?

Tags: java, web-services, unix, ksh

Need to call java ws from unix ksh script. Is there any possibility? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Curl](http://man.cx/curl) for that. However, parsing the results can get very nasty. You should consider using f.eg. python for that, which should be available on most installations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it with curl command, passing soap request envelope as an argument.

See [Calling WebService at the Unix command line](http://en.newinstance.it/2008/11/11/calling-webservice-at-the-unix-command-line/).